# Subquery is running faster than join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I am trying to identify value from one column which does exist in another column in same table

Sub query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Wear it With - Outfits 1` 
  FROM `product list` 
 WHERE `Wear it With - Outfits 1` NOT IN (SELECT `sku` 
                                            FROM `product list`)
```

...returns result in 2.7287sec

I tried to replace sub query by left join

```
   SELECT DISTINCT table1.`Wear it With - Outfits 1`
     FROM `product list` as table1 
LEFT JOIN `product list` as table2 ON table1.`Wear it With - Outfits 1`=table2.sku
     WHERE table2.sku IS NULL 
       AND table1.`Wear it With - Outfits 1` IS NOT NULL
```

...which returns result in 5.7651 sec

Normally joins return results much faster. So i believe i did something funny in my query?
But can not find any reason why my subquery is running faster than

Comment: yeap, MySQL and running those query through phpmyadmin

Comment: you really should have just simplified your example so instead of 'wear it with - outfits 1' just is replaced with 'foo' or similar. It makes it initially difficult to see what you're actually trying to do

Answer (score 4):

The statement 'Normally joins return results much faster.' is silly, especially without reference to any particular database system.

Many factors go into determining the performance of a particular query.  You can use the EXPLAIN tool in whatever database product you're using to determine exactly why the sub-query is preferable in this case (hint: it likely has to do with the use of the keyword DISTINCT).

Comment: sorry for not describing database system. I am using mysql and running those queries via phpmyadmin interface. Regarding distinct, i had a same doubt initially however when i tried query removing that still got a same result

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that your left join statement is not optimized .
The WHERE condition WHERE table2.sku IS NULL and table1.`Wear it With - Outfits 1` IS NOT NULL
 can waste a lot of time especially in this case.
You should optimize table2 before you left join.
PS:The number of records in table2 should reach a considerable amount.

Comment: from where condition i can not remove table2.sku is Null as its a basic way how you convert your not in subquery to join for reference (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) if i remove table.wear it with - Outfits 1 then it does make much change in time query took.